# Bind the browser scrollbar with modal window ofter it opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqmodal

When modal window is opened I want browser's scrollbar to be attached to this modal window so that scrolling will scroll down the modal window and initial page will remain locked. I have seen this in [getglue.com](http://getglue.com/feed). Here are screen shots attached or you can visit the site too.
Original
[image: Initial state]

Modal window is open now
[image: modal window]

As you can see the default scroll bar is now  binded to modal window and page at background is locked.
How this can be achieved ? I am using jqmodal plugin (if it helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is achieved by setting appropriate values for the CSS-property `overflow-y` on the the overlay and its container (see for example [this MDN-article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)).

Here's an example of how to achieve something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwXdD/